# gdbserver shared libraries

Tags: arm, libraries, shared, gdbserver

I'm working on ARM system with gdb 7.1 (i've tried 7.5 too). I'm using this tool to debug an
application composed by several shared libraries.

If I debug this application on the ARM side, with gdb 7.1 i can see the
shared loaded libraries (digiting "share"). Perfect!

I'm trying to do the same thing remotelly with gdb for arm on windows
host and gdbserver on ARM.

So I have:
1) gdb on windows for arm v.7.4.1 (i've tried 7.3.1 too)
2) gdbserver on arm v.7.1 (i've tried 7.5 too)

On Windows I can debug everything flawless except for the shared
libraries: infact, when i tried to digit "share" it says there isn't any
shared loaded libraries. I'm absolutely sure that at least one library
has loaded (on arm side the same situation works fine).

Any idea?

Edit:
probably i've found something:

In gcc on arm, when i ask for shared loaded libraries ("share") it calls function solib.c:info_sharedlibrary_command with full support for solib. (and it works fine)

Instead, when i ask for the same command on gdb on windows and gdbserver on arm, it passes the command "qXfer:libraries:read:" that doesn't manage any solib, only dlls! And the dlls list is obviously empty.

Did i miss something?

Solved! http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14670